# Datepicker datasave event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to use windows forms vb.net. Created a simple form with datepicker controls.

[image]

These controls are dynamically created. I am using infragistics datepicker here

```
dtpicker = New UltraDateTimeEditor
            dtpicker.Name = "Date" + i.ToString()
            dtpicker.MaskInput = "{date} hh:mm"
            dtpicker.MaskDisplayMode = MaskMode.IncludeBoth
            dtpicker.SpinButtonDisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.ButtonDisplayStyle.Always
            dtpicker.Height = 20
            dtpicker.Width = 140
            'horizontal
            dtpicker.Location = New Point((i * 140), 100)

            AddHandler dtpicker.Leave, AddressOf dtpicker_Leave
```

I have added leave event. But the problem is leave event is fired twice. Please suggest me how to fix or use other correct event.

My data saving logic on leave event looks like this

```
 If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtFlowPanel.Rows.Item(0).Item("ConveyanceID")) AndAlso Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtFlowPanel.Rows.Item(0).Item("TripID")) Then
        ScreenProperty.ARG_ConveyanceID = chkdtFlowPanel.Rows.Item(0).Item("ConveyanceID")
        ScreenProperty.ARG_TripID = chkdtFlowPanel.Rows.Item(0).Item("TripID")
        Dim prevDatevalue As Object = Nothing
        For Each o As Object In UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls
            If TypeOf (o) Is UltraDateTimeEditor Then
                Dim datePicker As UltraDateTimeEditor = o

                If prevDatevalue <> Nothing AndAlso datePicker.Value <> Nothing Then
                    If datePicker.Value < prevDatevalue Then
                        ' Do something Previous value is Lesser
                        'lblSuccess.Text = "Please verify date entered."
                        'lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Red
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
                ScreenProperty.ARG_CheckPointTimeID = Convert.ToInt32(datePicker.Tag.Split(","c)(0))
                ScreenProperty.ARG_TerminalCheckPointID = Convert.ToInt32(datePicker.Tag.Split(","c)(1))
                ScreenProperty.ARG_CheckPointTimeValue = datePicker.Value
                Helper.InsertCheckPointTimes(CType(ScreenProperty, KMCommonUITemplates.CUTScreenProperty), Me)
                prevDatevalue = datePicker.Value
                'lblSuccess.Text = "Data Saved Successfully."
                'lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Green
            End If
        Next
        'Else
        '    lblSuccess.Text = "Selected Order does not have Trip/Conveyance created."
        '    lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
    'Helper.GetCheckPointFlowByTerminalID(CType(ScreenProperty, KMCommonUITemplates.CUTScreenProperty), Me)
    ClearText()
```

Comment: I'd leave the button so you can get a positive and unmistakable cue from the user what to do.  Otherwise you could save/fail DataValidation because they Leave one control to go to another to Do Some Stuff.

Comment: But the user needs save datepicker control data upon date entered in editor

Comment: You shouldn't care about any `Leave` events.  If you want to perform validation then you should be handling the `Validating` event.  That is for validating that control only.  When it comes time to save, you call `ValidateChildren` on the form and that will raise the `Validating` event for every control and you only then save if they all pass.